# fetching specific object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In following example I am trying to get specific object from an array.First I am checking if it is there using find and after that getting only that object.

```js
const ppl = [
    { name: "emily", no: 1 },
    { name: "lily", no: 3 },
    { name: "sofeey", no: 5 }
];

function checkCoustomerNo(accNo) {
    return accNo.no === 1;
}
console.log(ppl.find(checkCoustomerNo).no + " " + "is avaiable");


function filterByValue(ppl, no) {
    return arr.filter(function (val) {
        return val[no] == 1;
    });
}

filterByValue(ppl, no);
```

Comment: Is there a question you are trying to ask?

Comment: The code is not working.

Comment: What is wrong in code?

Comment: `.find()` will return object, but `.filter()` will return array of objects. Why you are using two?

Comment: `return arr.filter()` it should be `return ppl.filter()`

Comment: Inside filter you are using ``value[no]``. Make ``no`` as string. The correct syntax is ``value['no']``. You can also use dot notation like you did in ``find``. Also don't use ``filter`` if you are already using ``find``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it in below snippet. Check it out.

```js
const ppl = [
    { name: "emily", no: 1 },
    { name: "lily", no: 3 },
    { name: "sofeey", no: 5 }
];

function checkCoustomerNo(accNo) {
    return accNo.no === 1;
}
console.log(ppl.find(checkCoustomerNo).no + " " + "is avaiable");


function filterByValue(arr, no) {
    return arr.filter(function (val) {
        return val.no == no;
    });
}

console.log(filterByValue(ppl, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ppl = [
    { name: "emily", no: 1 },
    { name: "lily", no: 3 },
    { name: "sofeey", no: 5 }
];
   
function filterByValue(arr = [], filter_no=null) {
    return arr.filter(function (val) {
        return val.no == filter_no;
    });
}

// Here you have to pass two parameter, 
// 1] Array 
// 2] Value for search in array
console.log(filterByValue(ppl, 1));
```